# Which crawlers are crawling my site

Tags: .htaccess, iis, web-crawler

Recently our main website has been a victim of two crawlers 80legs and magpie-crawler. Both where slowing down our website (80legs even crashed it). Now I am trying to find an effective way to track which spiders our crawling our website. I thought about storing the user-agent of each page request into a database for analyzes later. But i am not sure if this is the best way. Any comments or suggestion our appreciated.

BTW I am aware that checking the user-agent will not reveal all web-crawlers but i think for now this will be good enough.

Comment: Do you have the IP address they are using ? Filtering with the IP is the best option I guess.

Comment: I wish to know in general which crawlers our crawling our website. And for the record 80legs uses 1.000s of ip addresses worldwide.

Comment: You can recognize a crawler by its user-agent only. But any crawler can easily change its UA. Try to block access to your site by using IP black list(s), or block IPs by range.